# Как установить и использовать babel и watchers в PhpStotm на Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpstorm, webstorm, babel

Я скачал nodejs (v6.3.0 Current) с сайта https://nodejs.org/en/ и установил его.
Также я установил плагин `nodejs` в `phpstorm`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках шторма Settings → Languages&Frameworks → Node.js and NPM - я могу наблюдать данные настройки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее в терминале `phpStorm` я набираю команду

```
npm install --save-dev babel
```

И вижу папку `node_modules` в своем проекте, в котором есть `babel.js`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также я наблюдаю, что в настройках Settings → Languages&Frameworks → Node.js  →  добавился пакет `babel`

В настройках шторма `Npm packgage` я меняю путь с `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` на `myProjectDir/node_modules` (в моем случае это `D:\!work\!WEBServers\OpenServer\domains\dev.test.ru\node_modules`).
Почему? Да я сам не знаю почему. Видимо потому, что там теперь ведь этот самый бабель...

Далее создаю `js` файл с простым кодом:

```
let foo = () => console.log('test');
foo();
```

и пытаюсь добавить наблюдателя (watcher)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда что-то меняю в файле - шторм выдает мне ошибку

> An exception occurred while executing watcher 'Babel'. Watcher has been disabled. Fix it.: Cannot run program "D:!work!WEBServers\OpenServer\domains\dev.test.ru\node_modules\.bin\babel" (in directory "D:!work!WEBServers\OpenServer\domains\dev.test.ru\src"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 не является приложением Win32

---

Что я делаю не так? И куда надо нажать, чтобы мне стало хорошо?

Как, черт его дери, установить корректно и node и babel и другие расширения, типа gulp, grunt и прочих  в проект. И как добавить наблюдателей? Как?

Видео уж смотрел с инструкцией. Чувак ставит `babel` и у него даже в консоли спокойно доступна команда `babel something`... у меня - нет :-(

И другие инструкции читал - не работает нифига, так что не надо слать меня в гугл)

Comment: 1. D:!work!WEBServers\OpenServer\domains\dev.test.ru\node_modules.bin\babel - перед .bin должен быть \ 
2. попробуй запустить babel в консоли, напрямую, укажи абсолютный путь "D:!work!WEBServers\OpenServer\domains\dev.test.ru\node_modules\.bin\babel" без параметров

Comment: @RobertDampilon 1. у меня был слеш..просто ruSO что-то заэкранировал в моем вопросе, нехороший, а я и не заметил.........вообще какие настройки я только не пробовал..и по умолчанию - пишет ошибку выше и с макросами - пишет `An exception occurred while executing watcher 'Babel'. Watcher has been disabled. Fix it.: Invalid executable`.........А вообще, если в `package.json` указать настройку `"scripts": { "watch":"babel src -d out --presets es2015 -w" }` и далее просто в терминале `phpstrorm`набрать `npm run watch` - то все работает как часы...... а вот вотчер шторма парит мозг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывался.

На английском SO порекомендовали:

> try `babel.cmd` instead of just `babel`.

Я попробовал и это сработало. Все так просто >_<

---

В общем мои настройки таковы:

Program - `D:!work!WEBServers\OpenServer\domains\dev.test.ru\node_modules\.bin\babel` (или `$FileParentDir$\node_modules\.bin\babel.cmd` если через макрос)

Arguments - `--presets es2015 $FileDir$/test.js --out-file $FileParentDir$/out/test.js`

Working directory - `$FileParentDir$\src`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Или поле `Arguments` для вотчера, чтоб он наблюдал за целой папкой, вместо одного файла:

```
--presets es2015 $FileDir$ -d $FileParentDir$/out
```

---

Видимо с `gulp` и прочим дьявольским отродьем придется также поступать)